# F# implementation of the A* algorithm

Tags: beginner, f#, pathfinding, a-star

This is my first attempt at writing something useful in F# and in a functional way in general. I would appreciate if you could point out any issue, even details, as I'd like to put all the bad habits aside as soon as possible. I tried to leave my OOP comfort zone when I wrote this but I feel like this is not enough. I would love to hear suggestions about how to make this code more *functional*.

Please consider that the code in *Program.fs* is for testing only and has a lot of ugly stuffs in it (magic numbers, poor logic). I've put it here so that you can see how the code in *Pathfinding.fs* is used. The code in `main` creates the following grid with 10 rows and 10 columns and sets which nodes are obstacles:

```
0  1  . . . 9
10          19
.           .
.           .
.           .
90 91 . . . 99
```

Pathfinding.fs

```
module Pathfinding

//Classic Vector2 type with distances calculation
type Vector2 =
    {
        mutable X : float;
        mutable Y : float;
    } with

    member this.EuclideanDistance(otherVector:Vector2) =
        let distanceX = otherVector.X - this.X
        let distanceY = otherVector.Y - this.Y
        sqrt (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)

    member this.ManhattanDistance(otherVector:Vector2) =
        let distanceX = abs (otherVector.X - this.X)
        let distanceY = abs (otherVector.Y - this.Y)
        distanceX + distanceY

// Open = Available to get chosen as the starting point for a new recursion
// Closed = Already used during one recursion, not available anymore
// NotUsed = Ready to be opened, never used before
// Obstacle = Can't be used and won't be reset
type NodeState = Open = 0 | Closed = 1 | NotUsed = 2 | Obstacle = 3

//A possible point on paths
type Node =
    {
        mutable g : float;          //Sum of the distances between each nodes from the starting node to this one, following the parents
        mutable h : float;          //Sum of all the manhattan distance of the parents nodes and this node
        mutable id : int;           //Unique id
        mutable state : NodeState;
        mutable parentNode : Node option;
        mutable position : Vector2;
        mutable neighbours : Node list
    } with

    static member createEmpty = {g = 0.0; h = 0.0; id = -1; state = NodeState.NotUsed; parentNode = None; 
                                position = {X = 0.0; Y = 0.0}; neighbours = []}


    static member createWithPositionAndId position id = 
        let newNode = Node.createEmpty
        newNode.Position <- position
        newNode.Id <- id
        newNode

    member this.H 
        with public get() = this.h
        and public set value = this.h <- value

    member this.G 
        with public get() = this.g
        and public set value = this.g <- value

    member this.Position 
        with public get() = this.position
        and public set value = this.position <- value

    member this.F = this.g + this.h

    member this.Id 
        with public get() = this.id
        and public set value = this.id <- value

    member this.State
        with public get() = this.state
        and public set value = this.state <- value

    member this.ParentNode
        with public get() = this.parentNode.Value
        and public set newParentId =  this.parentNode <- Some(newParentId)

    //Returns the manhattan distance between this node and the specified node
    member this.ManHattanDistance (endNode:Node) = this.position.ManhattanDistance endNode.Position

    //Returns the euclidean distance between this node and the specified node
    member this.EuclideanDistance (endNode:Node) = this.position.EuclideanDistance endNode.Position 

    member this.AddNeighbour neighbour = this.neighbours <- neighbour :: this.neighbours

//Handles all the pathfinding stuffs
type Pathfinder =
    {
        mutable allNodes : Node list;
        mutable startNode : Node;
        mutable goalNode : Node;
        mutable currentNode : Node;
    } with

    static member create = {allNodes = []; startNode = Node.createEmpty; 
                            goalNode = Node.createEmpty; currentNode = Node.createEmpty}

    //Sets all the nodes to their NotUsed state except for the obstacles
    member private this.reset = 
        let resetNodeAction (node:Node) =   if not (node.State = NodeState.Obstacle) 
                                            then node.State <- NodeState.NotUsed
                                            node
        this.allNodes <- this.allNodes |> List.map (fun x -> x |> resetNodeAction)

    //Set the initial value to the currentNode
    member private this.init =
        this.currentNode <- this.startNode
        this.currentNode.State <- NodeState.Closed

    //Find the most viable node i.e. the open node that has the lowest F value
    member this.findMostViableNode =
        let mutable mostViableNode = this.allNodes.Item(0)
        let mutable mostViableValue = 9999999.0
        let rec loopAction (listTail:Node list) =
            match listTail with
            | [] -> mostViableNode
            | head :: tail ->   if (head.State = NodeState.Open) && (head.F < mostViableValue) then
                                    mostViableValue <- head.F
                                    mostViableNode <- head
                                loopAction tail
        loopAction this.allNodes

    //Add a node to the pathfinder
    member this.addNode node = this.allNodes <- node :: this.allNodes

    //Start a new path search
    member this.findPath startNode endNode =
        this.startNode <- startNode
        this.goalNode <- endNode
        this.init
        this.checkNeighbourNodes

    //Recursive function that expands the search for a path on the grid
    member private this.checkNeighbourNodes =
        match this.currentNode.Id with
        | x when x = this.goalNode.Id -> this.generatePathList this.currentNode this.startNode  //Reached the goal, generating the result

        | _ ->  //Process pathfinding data on current node's neighbours
                this.currentNode.neighbours <- this.currentNode.neighbours |> List.map (fun x -> this.processNodeData x this.currentNode) 

                if this.canContinue this.allNodes then      //Still need to search
                    this.currentNode <- this.findMostViableNode
                    this.currentNode.State <- NodeState.Closed
                    this.checkNeighbourNodes 
                else                                         //There is no possible result
                    []

    //Calculate all the pathfinding data for the given node Id and sets it as Open
    member private this.processNodeData currentNode parentNode =
        if currentNode.State = NodeState.NotUsed then 
            //Update euclidian distance
            currentNode.G <- (currentNode.EuclideanDistance parentNode) + parentNode.G
            //Update manhanttan distance
            currentNode.H <- (currentNode.ManHattanDistance this.goalNode ) + parentNode.H
            currentNode.ParentNode <- parentNode
            currentNode.State <- NodeState.Open
            currentNode
        else currentNode        

    //We found a path, this function generate a Vector2 list as a result
    member private this.generatePathList currentNode lastNode =
        let mutable result = [currentNode.Position]
        match currentNode.Id with 
        | x when x = lastNode.Id -> result
        | _ ->  result <- (this.generatePathList currentNode.ParentNode lastNode) @ result
                result

    //Return true if any node is in the Open state.
    member private this.canContinue nodeList =
        match nodeList with
        | [] -> false
        | head :: tail ->   if head.State = NodeState.Open then
                                true
                            else
                                this.canContinue tail
```

Program.fs

```
open Pathfinding

let mutable nodeList = []

//Create a node a the given position and add it to the list
let addNodeToList (x:int) (y:int) =
    let newNode = Node.createWithPositionAndId {X = (float)x; Y = (float)y} (99 - nodeList.Length)
    nodeList <- newNode :: nodeList

//Create a row of the map
let rec createMapRow rowPosition (currentRowSize:int) =
    match currentRowSize with
    | x when x = -1 -> ()
    | _ ->  addNodeToList currentRowSize rowPosition
            createMapRow rowPosition (currentRowSize - 1)

//Generate all the nodes
let rec createMap currentColumnSize maxRowSize =
    match currentColumnSize with
    | x when x = -1 -> ()
    | _ ->  createMapRow currentColumnSize maxRowSize 
            createMap (currentColumnSize - 1) maxRowSize

//Add the node of the given id as a neighbour to the given node
let addOneNeighbour (currentNode:Node) idToAdd =
    let n = nodeList.Item(idToAdd)
    currentNode.AddNeighbour n

//Associate neighbours to nodes and consider grid sides.
// A    B       C
// D    node    E
// F    G       H
let addNeighbours (currentNode:Node) id (nodeList:Node list) =
    let x = currentNode.Position.X
    let y = currentNode.Position.Y
    let inFisrtColumn = (x = 0.0)
    let inLastColumn = (x = 9.0)

    if not inFisrtColumn then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 1)        //D
    if not inLastColumn then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 1)        //E

    if id >= 10 then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 10)       //B
        if not inFisrtColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 11)   //A
        if not inLastColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 9)    //C
    if id < 90 then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 10)       //G
        if not inFisrtColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 9)    //F
        if not inLastColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 11)   //H

    currentNode

//Iterates over nodes and for each node calls addNeighbours
let assignNeighbours (nodeList:Node list) =
    let action i n = addNeighbours n i nodeList
    let list = List.mapi action nodeList
    list

//Iterates over nodes and register each node to the pathfinder
let assignNodesToPathfinder (nodeList:Node list) (pathfinder:Pathfinder) =
    let action n = pathfinder.addNode n
    let list = List.map action nodeList
    nodeList

let setAsObstacle id =
    let nodeToClose = nodeList.Item(id)
    nodeToClose.State <- NodeState.Obstacle


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    createMap 9 9
    nodeList <- assignNeighbours nodeList

    setAsObstacle 1
    setAsObstacle 11
    setAsObstacle 21
    setAsObstacle 22

    let pathfinder = Pathfinder.create
    nodeList <- assignNodesToPathfinder nodeList pathfinder

    let mutable startNode = nodeList.Item(0)
    let mutable goalNode = nodeList.Item(5)
    let mutable path = pathfinder.findPath startNode goalNode
    printfn "%A" path    
    startNode <- nodeList.Item(99)
    goalNode <- nodeList.Item(0)
    path <- pathfinder.findPath startNode goalNode
    printfn "%A" path

    0 // retourne du code de sortie entier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, F# is written in functional style, and there are several things you are not doing in functional style here.

> ```
> type Vector2 =
>     {
>         mutable X : float;
>         mutable Y : float;
>     } with
>
>     member this.EuclideanDistance(otherVector:Vector2) =
>         let distanceX = otherVector.X - this.X
>         let distanceY = otherVector.Y - this.Y
>         sqrt (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)
>
>     member this.ManhattanDistance(otherVector:Vector2) =
>         let distanceX = abs (otherVector.X - this.X)
>         let distanceY = abs (otherVector.Y - this.Y)
>         distanceX + distanceY
> ```

`X` and `Y` should not be mutable here.  You should write these as a [record](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/records/):

```
type Vector2 = { X :float; Y :float }
```

Then, instead of having class members, you would make the `EuclideanDistance` and `ManhattanDistance` pure functions:

```
let euclideanDistance (vector1 :Vector2) (vector2: Vector2) =
    let distanceX = vector2.X - vector1.X
    let distanceY = vector2.Y - vector1.Y
    sqrt (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)

let manhattanDistance (vector1 :Vector2) (vector2: Vector2) =
    let distanceX = abs (vector2.X - vector1.X)
    let distanceY = abs (vector2.Y - vector1.Y)
    distanceX + distanceY
```

You will probably be able to remove the type hints as well, and F# will still be able to figure out what types the parameters are.

---

In a few places you assign a variable, then immediately return the variable.  Instead of this, you should return the result of the calculation.  One such place is here:

> ```
> member private this.generatePathList currentNode lastNode =
>     let mutable result = [currentNode.Position]
>     match currentNode.Id with 
>     | x when x = lastNode.Id -> result
>     | _ ->  result <- (this.generatePathList currentNode.ParentNode lastNode) @ result
>             result
> ```

That should be rewritten as:

```
member private this.generatePathList currentNode lastNode =
    match currentNode.Id with 
    | x when x = lastNode.Id -> [currentNode.Position]
    | _ -> (this.generatePathList currentNode.ParentNode lastNode) @ [currentNode.Position]
```

---

This looks like a bug:

> ```
> let assignNodesToPathfinder (nodeList:Node list) (pathfinder:Pathfinder) =
>     let action n = pathfinder.addNode n
>     let list = List.map action nodeList
>     nodeList
> ```

You iterate the list and create a new list based on the action, but return the original list and do nothing with the new list.  Unless `pathfinder.addNode` has side effects somehow, in which case you should `ignore` the result of the `List.map`.  Given the name of the function, it looks as if you really just want a `void` result, so you can return a `unit`, which is essentially the same.  The `unit` literal in F# is `()`, but you can also get it by returning a `unit` from another expression.  Give these assumptions, I would write it as:

```
let assignNodesToPathfinder (nodeList:Node list) (pathfinder:Pathfinder) =
    ignore <| List.map pathfinder.addNode nodeList
```

Notice that if you have a function that takes a single parameter and returns a new result, you can just place it inline like the way I did above.

Another way to write it would be using tail recursion:

```
let rec assignNodesToPathfinder (nodeList:Node list) (pathfinder:Pathfinder) =
    let head::tail = nodeList
    pathfinder.addNode head

    if not tail.IsEmpty then
        assignNodesToPathfinder tail pathfinder
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I don't really know when I should use a record  or a class. Should Node be rewritten with the same logic? Should Pathfinder disappear completely and be replaced by functions only? **Maybe I should read more about functional programming!**

Comment: You typically want to use F# types (records, unions, and such) over classes and structs.  Typically, you avoid state and mutable variables in FP and use pure functions and immutability.

Comment: Continuing along that line, in `assignNodesToPathfinder`, you would typically construct a new `Pathfinder` instance with the new nodes and return it (and update the name to represent the new action).

Comment: This makes sense, the Pathfinder is defined by the map it holds. Also I realize I used List.map several time in the code when I just wanted to iterate over the list, not when I wanted to create a new list with the result (as you pointed in your answer). I'll fix that too.

Comment: One way to do that is recursion, which also supports early-returns, if that is an option.

Comment: I guess there is no need for `let mutable result = [currentNode.Position]` in the `generatePathList` function you wrote?