# F# implementation of the A* algorithm round 2

Tags: beginner, f#, pathfinding, a-star

This is my second attempt at implementing the A* algorithm using F#, the first one is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152064/f-implementation-of-the-a-algorithm).

What I changed:

- I removed the Node class and added two records named `MapNode` and `PathNode` that respectively store map and pathfinding data. This leads to more immutable variables and an implementation that will help split pre-computed data and runtime data.
- I removed the Pathfinder class and only use functions instead
- I changed the implementation of `canContinue` to use `List.exists`
- I did all the modification suggested by *@Dain II Ironfoot* in the previous post

It feels better to works like this with F# but it looks a bit messy too. As in the previous question, all suggestions are welcome!

Pathfinding.fs

```
module PathfindingRound2

type Vector2 = { X : float; Y : float; } 

let euclideanDistance v1 v2 =
        let distanceX = v2.X - v1.X
        let distanceY = v2.Y - v1.Y
        sqrt (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)

let manhattanDistance v1 v2 =
        let distanceX = abs (v2.X - v1.X)
        let distanceY = abs (v2.Y - v1.Y)
        distanceX + distanceY


//Possible states of a MapNode:
// Walkable = Can be used in a path
// Obstacle = Can't be used in a path
type MapNodeState = Walkable = 0 | Obstacle = 1

// A node that store map related data, no pathfinding data here
type MapNode = { uniqueId:int; position:Vector2; mutable neighbours: MapNode list; mutable state:MapNodeState }

let createMapNode id position state=
    { uniqueId = id; position = position; neighbours = []; state = state} 

//Possible states of a PathNode
// Open = Available to get chosen as the starting point for a new recursion
// Closed = Already used during one recursion, not available anymore
// NotUsed = Ready to be opened, never used before
type PathNodeState = Open = 0 | Closed = 1 | NotUsed = 2

//A node that stores pathfinding related data and links them with a mapNode
type PathNode = { g:int; h:int; parent:PathNode option; mutable state:PathNodeState; mapNode:MapNode }

//Sum of the distances between each nodes from the starting node to this one, following the parents
let calculateNodeG parentG parent targetMapNode = 
    parentG + int(euclideanDistance parent.mapNode.position targetMapNode.position)

//Sum of all the manhattan distance of the parents nodes and this node
let calculateNodeH parentH parent targetMapNode = 
    parentH + int(manhattanDistance parent.mapNode.position targetMapNode.position)

let calculateNodeF node = node.g + node .h

let createPathNode parentG parentH targetMapNode parent = 
    let newG = calculateNodeG parentG parent targetMapNode
    let newH = calculateNodeH parentH parent targetMapNode
    { g = newG; h = newH; parent = Some parent; state = PathNodeState.Open; mapNode = targetMapNode }


//PATHFINDING FUNCTIONS

//We found a path, this function generates a Vector2 list as a result
let rec generatePathList currentNode lastNode =
    match currentNode.mapNode.uniqueId with 
    | x when x = lastNode.uniqueId -> [currentNode.mapNode.position]
    | _ ->  match currentNode.parent with
            | Some parent -> (generatePathList parent lastNode) @ [currentNode.mapNode.position]
            | None ->   printfn "Logic error, lastNode should be the only node with parent = None. Returning computed path."
                        [currentNode.mapNode.position]

//Return true if any node is in the Open state.
let canContinue nodeList =
    nodeList |> List.exists (fun n -> n.state = PathNodeState.Open)

let isAlreadyInThePath nodeList node =
    nodeList |> List.exists (fun n -> n.mapNode.uniqueId = node.uniqueId)

//Find the most viable node i.e. the open node that has the lowest F value
//At this point we know that nodeList is no empty.
let findMostViableNode (nodeList:PathNode list) =
    let mutable mostViableNode = nodeList.Head
    let mutable mostViableValue = 9999999
    let rec loopAction listTail =
        match listTail with
        | [] -> mostViableNode
        | head :: tail ->   let nodeF = calculateNodeF head
                            if (head.state = PathNodeState.Open) && (nodeF < mostViableValue) then
                                mostViableValue <- nodeF
                                mostViableNode <- head
                            loopAction tail
    loopAction nodeList

//Calculate all the pathfinding data for the given node Id and sets it as Open
let processNodeData nodeList currentNode =
    let mutable neighbourPathNodes = []
    let rec loopAction neighbours currentNode =
        match neighbours with
        | [] -> neighbourPathNodes
        | head :: tail ->   if not (isAlreadyInThePath nodeList head) then   //Don't add duplicated node
                                if head.state = MapNodeState.Walkable then  //Only use walkable nodes
                                    neighbourPathNodes <- (createPathNode currentNode.g currentNode.h head currentNode) :: neighbourPathNodes
                            loopAction tail currentNode
    loopAction currentNode.mapNode.neighbours currentNode

//Recursively looks for a path
let rec checkNeighboursNode nodeList startNode endNode currentNode =
    match currentNode.mapNode.uniqueId with
    | x when x = endNode.uniqueId -> generatePathList currentNode startNode
    | _ ->  let openNodeList = (processNodeData nodeList currentNode) @ nodeList
            if canContinue openNodeList then
                let newCurrentNode = findMostViableNode openNodeList
                newCurrentNode.state <- PathNodeState.Closed
                checkNeighboursNode openNodeList startNode endNode newCurrentNode
            else
                []  //There is no path to the goal node

//Initiate pathfinding routine
let findPath startNode endNode =
    let currentNode = { g = 0; h = 0; parent = None; state = PathNodeState.Closed; mapNode = startNode }
    checkNeighboursNode [] startNode endNode currentNode
```

Program.fs

```
open PathfindingRound2

//let pathfinder = Pathfinder.create
let mutable nodeList = []

//Create a node a the given position and add it to the list
let addNodeToList x y =
    let node = createMapNode (99 - nodeList.Length) {X = (float)x; Y = (float)y} MapNodeState.Walkable;
    nodeList <- node :: nodeList

//Create a row of the map
let rec createMapRow rowPosition (currentRowSize:int) =
    match currentRowSize with
    | x when x = -1 -> ()
    | _ ->  addNodeToList currentRowSize rowPosition
            createMapRow rowPosition (currentRowSize - 1)

//Generate all the nodes
let rec createMap currentColumnSize maxRowSize =
    match currentColumnSize with
    | x when x = -1 -> ()
    | _ ->  createMapRow currentColumnSize maxRowSize 
            createMap (currentColumnSize - 1) maxRowSize

//Add the node of the given id as a neighbour to the given node
let addOneNeighbour currentNode idToAdd =
    let n = nodeList.Item(idToAdd)
    currentNode.neighbours <- n :: currentNode.neighbours

//Associate neighbours to nodes and consider grid sides.
// A    B       C
// D    node    E
// F    G       H
let addNeighbours currentNode id nodeList =
    let x = currentNode.position.X
    let y = currentNode.position.Y
    let inFisrtColumn = (x = 0.0)
    let inLastColumn = (x = 9.0)

    if not inFisrtColumn then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 1)        //D
    if not inLastColumn then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 1)        //E

    if id >= 10 then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 10)       //B
        if not inFisrtColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 11)   //A
        if not inLastColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id - 9)    //C
    if id < 90 then
        addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 10)       //G
        if not inFisrtColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 9)    //F
        if not inLastColumn then
            addOneNeighbour currentNode (id + 11)   //H

    currentNode

//Iterates over nodes and for each node calls addNeighbours
let assignNeighbours nodeList =
    let action i n = addNeighbours n i nodeList
    List.mapi action nodeList |> ignore

let closeNode id =
    let nodeToClose = nodeList.Item(id)
    nodeToClose.state <- MapNodeState.Obstacle


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    createMap 9 9
    assignNeighbours nodeList

    closeNode 1
    closeNode 11
    closeNode 21
    closeNode 22

    let mutable startNode = nodeList.Item(0)
    let mutable goalNode = nodeList.Item(5)
    let mutable path = findPath startNode goalNode
    printfn "%A" path
    startNode <- nodeList.Item(99)
    goalNode <- nodeList.Item(0)
    path <- findPath startNode goalNode
    printfn "%A" path

    0 // retourne du code de sortie entier
```

Comment: Looks much better.  I'd suggest trying to remove `mutable` entirely and reducing `if`s in favor of `match`es.  I was told that `if` should only be used when checking a boolean variable.

Comment: I don't know how I can remove the last `mutable`s without over complicating the code. I'll try to find a solution to this.